# HTTPoxy - What about HTTPS_PROXY when dealing with HTTPoxy vulnerability?

Tags: tls, vulnerability, nginx, httpoxy

`fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY "";` is the soluntion, but why didn't they also mention HTTPS_PROXY? I have a HTTPS website, not HTTP.

Should I also add `fastcgi_param HTTPS_PROXY "";` or not?

Stop changing the title.

Comment: I think you need some more context! Who are "they"? What exactly are you trying to do? Since you have tagged it with nginx, I guess you are configuring and nginx server? Please [edit] your question to include relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the context is missing I think you are referring to the [httpoxy](https://httpoxy.org/) vulnerability where it is possible for an remote attacker to set the HTTP_PROXY environment variable using a HTTP `Proxy` header. The base of this vulnerability is that in a CGI environment the `HTTP_xxx` environment variable is set if the HTTP header `xxx` exists. Since this only affects `HTTP_*` variables and not `HTTPS_*` variables it does not affect `HTTPS_PROXY`.

Apart from that both `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` are only relevant for requests done by the CGI script and is not related to how your site gets accessed.